# select text in textbox: extract word from caret position without selection

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a problem and I want to see if you can help me.

What I look for is that when I right click on a word inside a `TexBox` tell me about which word I am posed, and then I can add that word to the dictionary that I already have created.

My code:

```
If textbox1.SelectedText <> "" Then 
     Dim agr As String = textbox1.SelectedText.Remove(textbox1.SelectedText.Length - 1) 
     MsgBox(agr) 
Else 
     MsgBox("Select a word by double click to add it to the dictionary") 
End If
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you looked into so far?  Can you add any code to show us?

Comment: "tell me about which word I am posed" I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit on what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: When I right click on an underlined word and want to add it to my personalized spellcheck dictionary it doesn't work. Now, if instead i selectiontext it, and then add it, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you tried?

Comment: If textbox1.SelectedText <> "" Then
            Dim agr As String = textbox1.SelectedText.Remove(textbox1.SelectedText.Length - 1)
           msgbox(agr)
        Else
          MsgBox("Debe seleccionar la palabra acciendo doble click>sobre la misma para agregarla al diccionario")
      End If

Comment: You should add code to your question as in comment it is a mess... Look I edited ur question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this code will solve your problem. If it works for you then please mark it as Solved so that future readers get the confirmation. And ask me any query about it if you got any in the comment section below.

```
Private Sub Textbox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Textbox1.MouseDown
    If MouseButtons.Right Then
        If Textbox1.TextLength - Textbox1.Text.IndexOf(" ", 0) > Textbox1.SelectionStart Then
            Textbox1.Select((Textbox1.Text.LastIndexOf(" ", Textbox1.SelectionStart) + 1), (Textbox1.Text.IndexOf(" ", Textbox1.SelectionStart) - (Textbox1.Text.LastIndexOf(" ", Textbox1.SelectionStart) + 1)))
        Else
            Textbox1.Select(Textbox1.Text.LastIndexOf(" ", Textbox1.TextLength) + 1, Textbox1.TextLength - Textbox1.Text.LastIndexOf(" ", Textbox1.TextLength))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a property which is called `SelectionStart`, representing the position of the caret in the textbox. Its value will be valid also when there is nothing selected.

Loop left from there, until you encounter a word boundary or zero. Then loop right until you encounter a word boundary or Len-1. Use the two offsets you got this way, to extract the word around the caret with the `SubString` function.

Comment: Great thank you very much, I understand well the idea that you explain to me, but you could give me an example because I do not know how to apply it.

Discourage the inconvenience and thanks for helping me